# Superfish expanded menu doesn't close when clicking outside

Tags: jquery, html, drupal, menu

I have this expanded Superfish menu with markup:

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="true">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
```

and:

```
<div id="navbar-collapse" class="navbar-collapse collapse in" aria-expanded="true" style="">
        <div class="region region-navigation-collapsible">
<section id="block-mainmenu" class="block block-superfish block-superfishmain clearfix">...</section></div></div>
```

I want this menu close when clicking outside of it.

I tried this jQuery code:

```
var $menu = $('.menu');
var $button = $('.navbar-toggle');

$button.click(function () {
  $menu.toggle();
});

$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
   if (!$menu.is(e.target) 
   && $menu.has(e.target).length === 0
   && !$button.is(e.target)) 
   {
     $menu.hide();
     $button.addClass("collapsed");
     $button.attr("aria-expanded","false");
     $("#navbar-collapse").attr("aria-expanded","false");
     $("#navbar-collapse").removeClass("in");
  }
 });
```

but it doesn't work right. It closes at first click outside but then clicking again on the button it doesn't open as it should.
It is aria-expanded, classes and the superfish.js that mess things up.

It is not a duplicate of other simplified menus that close on clicking outside, as its behaviour is much more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone interested in the future, done in a simplier way by triggering the button:

```
var $button = $('.navbar-toggle');
$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
  if ($('#navbar-collapse').hasClass('in')) 
  {
     $button.trigger("click"); 
  }
});
```